# Google Analytics conversion tracking - referrals from payment provider

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, conversions

I have a question regarding conversion tracking using Google Analytics. My client uses an external payment service provider - SecureTrading.

**Problem:** All website visitors who would like to make a purchase are taken to a payment form on https://securetrading.net and are redirected back after a successful payment. Google Analytics counts that as a referral and messes up conversion tracking stats.

**Question:** What needs to be changed / added in the payment forms or Google Analytics settings so that the conversions would be assigned to the right traffic sources.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** use cross-domain tracking

> **E-commerce transactions: crossing between domains**
>
> If you require that visitors cross domains during the checkout process
>   on your site, you must ensure that you have added the necessary lines
>   to your tracking code. Please refer to the FAQ on tracking 3rd-party
>   shopping baskets for more information. If you do not add these lines
>   to the tracking code, the referring-source information gets dropped
>   when a visitor navigates between the domains and the transactions in
>   your reports may be attributed to direct visits instead of CPC or
>   organic traffic.

- [Source #1](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2772342)
- [Source #2](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en-GB)